# How to use selenium on Repl.it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, replit

I am trying to use Selenium in Repl but for some reason it does not seem to work is there a way I can fix this?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")

views = driver.find_element_by_class("view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer")
print(views)
```

Here are the two errors I seem to be getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/JustStuff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/runner/JustStuff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/runner/JustStuff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/runner/JustStuff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Comment: Are you copying the Chrome driver onto that system?  Are you even allowed to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go to replit.nix , click on hidden files and you are going to see it,
you need to import pkgs.chromium and pkgs.chromedriver into deps

```
{ pkgs }: {
deps = [
    pkgs.python38Full
    pkgs.chromium
    pkgs.chromedriver
];
```

don't forget to  refresh the page

Comment: what do you mean by replit.nix? 
that TLD doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Dec 2023.

Step 1: create a new Python Replit project;

Step 2: add a new file called `replit.nix`. Its contents should be:

```
{ pkgs }: {
  deps = [
    pkgs.geckodriver
    pkgs.ungoogled-chromium
    pkgs.chromedriver
  ];
}
```

Step 3: Add the following code to `main.py` and run it. It should print `10`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

options.add_argument("start-maximized"); 
options.add_argument("disable-infobars"); 
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions"); 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu"); 
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://hoffa.medium.com')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
print(html.count('<article>'))
```

Replit project: https://replit.com/@zyxxy/Selenium2023

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638309/1396516